# Make batch script command explicit rather than implicit

Tags: batch, batch-file

The below bat file only works inside the specific folder the bat file resides and I would like it to work outside of that folder or at least a different folder than where the batch script resides. I am new to bat files and unsure but I have tried a few things without success.

This code will delete part of a file name, "`_page`" set as variable below.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set deletestring=_page
echo Ready to start
echo.
pause
echo.
for /f  "delims==" %%F in ('dir /b /l *.png  ^| find "%deletestring%"') do (
    set oldfilename=%%F
    set newfilename=!oldfilename:%deletestring%=!
     Ren "!oldfilename!" "!newfilename!"
    )
```

Comment: Use `pushd "path to a folder"` somewhere before the `for /F "delims=" %%F in …` loop.

Comment: @Kory .... Did you ever get around to looking over the answer provided here to see if it helps any? Give me an update on your status with this when you get to it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `*.png` to be `"c:\folder\path\*.png"` and then the batch command within the [`for`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop should run from any folder against that full explicit path for the `.png` files. Just set the `.png` folder path as the `src=` variable value and use that in the [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command of the for loop.

### Example Script

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set deletestring=_page
set src=c:\folder\path
echo Ready to start
echo.
pause
echo.
for /f  "delims==" %%F in ('dir /b /l "%src%\*.png"  ^| find "%deletestring%"') do (
    set oldfilename=%%F
    set newfilename=!oldfilename:%deletestring%=!
    Ren "!oldfilename!" "!newfilename!"
    )
```

> ### Script Clarification
>
> ### [image]

---

### Further Resources

- [Dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)